# Azure PIM role activation in B2B environment

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How do you activate a PIM role that you have been assigned in a B2B relationship, where the role is not in your default tenant? When you go to MyRoles it only shows the roles for your default tenant, and I do not see any way to switch tenants from there.

MyRoles only shows the roles from your default domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch to the guest tenant (top right corner the settings icon left of your user).
After that, you can go again to your PIM blade and claim the required role.

I hope this helps!

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Wish I'd seen your answer before I posted my own and before I found it on my own, LOL

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is wondering, this is what I figured out on my own ... On the My Roles click on the settings gear. It then gives an option to change directory. You can then change to the other directory. Then you still need to activate the role for that directory, but after that you will be able to function in the other tenant with that PIM role.